# How does angularjs binding work when copying objects?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have several html checkbox that is either on/off based on the properties of an object inside of an array say: objectArray.get(i).isCheckBoxActive. Since the user can change the object properties I'm trying to implement a button that reset all changes. My idea was creating a copy of objectArray (say objectArrayOriginal) and when the button is clicked it calls a function that copies back objectArrayOriginal into objectArray. I would expect that if a checkBox is off in objectArrayOriginal then, after pressing the button, it should be off also in the html page. To copy the object I did:

```
var objectArrayOriginal = JSON.stringify(objectArray)
.....
function clickReset(){
  vm.objectArray = JSON.stringify(objectArrayOriginal)
}
```

I checked and although the field objectArray.get(i).isCheckBoxActive gets reset to its original value; the checkboxes remain checked/unchecked. The solution I found to be working is iterating over objectArray and comparing the values one by one with objectArrayOriginal. I would like to understand why the previous method fails and if there's a better one. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There's actually an easy way to do this using ng-model - if you actually post the relevant HTML and script it'll be much easier to help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you need to be leveraging ng-repeat for your array. You should not be accessing individual elements of an array outside of an ngRepeat, it makes change tracking harder than it needs to be. Replacing objects that your template has already bound to is synonymous with throwing away that instance of the DOM. As Kinglish said, post relevant source and we can better advise.